# How to prevent iOS keyboard from pushing up navigation bar on WKWebView

Tags: ios, swift, angularjs, uikit, wkwebview

How do I prevent iOS Keyboard from pushing up the navigation bar on a WKwebView?On android this problem doesn't happen but on iOS it does. Please refer to these [images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9FJmu.png)

Comment: Have you used UINavigationController with UINavigationBar or it custom designed UIView?

Comment: It's a custom navigation bar from the web side using angularJS. The iOS app is just entire a webView that is written in AngularJS

Answer (score 0):

Here, hierarchy should be

```
UIWindow -> UINavigationController -> UIViewController -> WKwebView
```

You can assign `UINavigationController` as child of `UIWindow` rootViewController

```
window?.rootViewController = CustomNavigationController()
```

When you have this, your `UIViewController` will be child of `UINavigationController` and your logic of scrolling view or rearranging any UI elements will not effect the `UINavigationBar` visibility until you manually set it.

Once you have above hierarchy, you can access `UINavigationBar` as `self.navigationBar`

Comment: The navigation Bar is actually a custom nav bar made in angularJS. The entire iOS app is a WKWebView screen. Will your solution still solve the error?

Comment: So your application is just a web view and you are loading content from web. In this case, at client side, you have only one UI element i.e. web view and keyboard will definitely push entire screen data (including nav bar) to up.

Comment: If you wanted to avoid that, then you should have `UINavigationBar` and 'WebView` as 2 separate client UI element.